# How bad is to buy domain name with .ext from another country even if they allow non citizens to own one?

Tags: privacy, webserver

I'd like to purchase a domain name from a country that does not require citizenship, since they can make nice urls, they are more available and sometimes not too expensive too!

But few things annoys me and it could compromise services under that domain name.

- **[DNSSEC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Domain_Name_System_Security_Extensions)**
  Not everyone uses it and sets it up properly but many exotic (non industrialised) country extensions [won't even support it](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Internet_top-level_domains#Country_code_top-level_domains)
- **Local company that registers that name.**
  Even if I would have a domain name before a company in that country register itself with that name. won't I most likely lose my not much existing rights under that extension?. Unless **Internet Corporation for Assigned Names and Numbers (ICANN)** as a say in this?
- **Someone with easy access in the government of that country with annoying intentions**
  I know the part where you set a domain's dns servers and they would get queried and return info about that domain. I can have control over the dns. Unless they must be within that country? What about above dns. I don't know how it works where you set the dns servers of a domain. And above that too! If servers in that country are doing some part of the process? And if it could easily be tampered with or is there a procedure by which it all goes smoothly and (a bit more) securely?
- **Domain name resolving suddenly to another ip**
  A lot could be done to harm what was happening before this change. Everyone who was relying on dns resolution for my domain name, could end up on someone that replicated some of the services this domain was answering. For example, they could record usernames and passwords being sent to them, and then trying them out on the old IP this name was resolving to! A nightmare I don't want to see.

Should I even consider buying a domain name from another country than my own, provided they allow it? Or am I asking for possibly and easily a lot of trouble and long term insecurity about it?

Comment: This is about SEO, not security, but be aware that Google will think you are targeting your site at users in the country that the domain belongs to, rather than where you actually are, and last time I checked there was no way to override this.

Comment: You mean it's another hindrance, which I hadn't thought of. Thanks. I don't mind SEO at all in this case but I do mind services like emails, dns (which I wouldn't serve with this name in this case), and others.

Comment: You may need to specify which countries you are worried about. The practices you describe definitely do not occur frequently if at all in e.g. the EU.

Answer (score 1):

I own quite a few domain names registered in countries (with that country's extension) that I do not live in nor do I have the citizenship of that country. I am not aware of country extensions that require citizenship. (which does not mean they don't exist, but at the very least that they are rare).

Also, this may be more of a question for the webmasters stack exchange, see [similar](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/8636/does-co-uk-domains-need-a-uk-citizen) question from some time ago.

Comment: See he link in my question.. .ca, .fr, .eu, .it requires it for example. You can still try to register them but they have laws they can easily challenge and defeat you with if they want and you don't meet the requirements.

Comment: I own .eu and .fr domain names. Not an FR national and the EU is not a country, no special requirements (that I am aware of or was ever confronted with). Every country has regulations to close or disown domains that infringe on local law, but that seems normal?

Comment: For .fr u need to be a business in france or 3-4 other countries and have valid contact info in those territories (which excludes .us and everything else). But they allow proxies which mean ur domain name provider is the registrant for your domain name instead of yourself. Which may be good I think since they are a bigger company!